# Extract hostname from a given domain string and remove extension and www

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I'm trying to extract the hostname and simply return the part of the domain without the `www.` and any extension, for some reason, my current code and regex isn't really working for non-www variants and is returning `unknown`, I'm not sure why?

```js
function getGeneratedBrand (url) {
  const brand = (url.match(/([^.]+)\.\w{2,3}(?:\.\w{2})?$/) || [])[1]
  return brand != null ? brand : 'unknown'
}

console.log(getGeneratedBrand('https://example.com/')) <-- doesn't work, returned "unknown"

console.log(getGeneratedBrand('www.example.com')) <-- working
```

How can I modify my regex to make it more robust with protocol stripping and param stripping?

Comment: Isn't it easier to use the `URL()` constructor to get the host/hostname? Of course it wouldn't work for `www.example.com` but you can just add a dummy protocol in the front to get it to work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use built in `URL.hostname` and replace www.

```
console.log(new URL('https://example.com/').hostname.replace('www.', ''))
console.log(new URL('https://www.example.com/').hostname.replace('www.', ''))
```

`URL` can be used in most of the browsers https://caniuse.com/?search=URL

Comment: Great, how would I remove the extension from this without knowing the extension?

Comment: `.split('.')[0]` after removed `www.`

Comment: Thanks for that! Completely mind blanked to that one